# Not able to read the actual message sent to TcpListener

Tags: .net, c++-cli, tcplistener

I want to send a message from the browser to my .NET application, I heard about the `System::Net::Sockets::TcpListener` and found it interesting for that job.

I have a `CLR Console App` (.NET Framework 4.8).

Here's how I'm using `System::Net::Sockets::TcpListener` in my TCPlistener.cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    TcpListener^ tcpListener = nullptr;
    TcpClient^ tcpClient = nullptr;
    NetworkStream^ stream = nullptr;
    try {
        IPAddress^ ipAddress = Dns::GetHostEntry("localhost")->AddressList[0];
        tcpListener = gcnew TcpListener(ipAddress, 7651);
        tcpListener->Start();
        Console::WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        tcpClient = tcpListener->AcceptTcpClient();
        Console::WriteLine("Connected!");
        array<Byte>^ bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
        System::String^ data = nullptr;
        stream = tcpClient->GetStream();
        int i;
        while ((i = stream->Read(bytes, 0, bytes->Length)) != 0) {
            data = System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            Console::WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException^ exception) {
        Console::WriteLine(exception);
    }
    finally {
        if (tcpClient != nullptr) {
            tcpClient->Close();
        }

        if (stream != nullptr) {
            stream->Close();
        }

        if (tcpListener != nullptr) {
            tcpListener->Stop();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's my html with javascript:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script>
        function postMessage() {
            const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7651');
            socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
                socket.send('Hello World!');
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="postMessage()">Post Message</button>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the output when the button is clicked:

```
Waiting for a connection...
Connected!
Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7651
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.47
Upgrade
Received: : websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: xtmy+Ue3tc48BKn37QLozA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

Why there is no `"Hello World!"` in the output? It looks like `socket.send('Hello World!')` didn't work or I'm not reading it properly from my TCPlistener.cpp file.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

Answer (score 0):

@Simple. You are looking for an implementation of WebSocket Server, using TCP Sockets. It's possible but you must deal with the [Handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-14) to accept a connection and start to send and receive data. In your case, you are not performing Handshaking.

Let me share with you a personal project in C# where I implement a Websocket Server with TCPListener and TCPClient, the socket client shows you how to deal with the Handshaking and send/receive data:

https://github.com/jorgemedra/WebSocketAPI/blob/master/WebSocket/WebSocket/WebSocketClient.cs

This is the whole [repository](https://github.com/jorgemedra/WebSocketAPI).

I hope it could help you.